# TokenMismatchException after hosting

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

I have developed a web site using laravel 5.4. in localhost its works fine. 

after i uploaded it into cpanel shared host. its keep getting the

(1/1) TokenMismatchException
in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 68) 
Error when i tried to login to the web site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all use in login form (in html view):

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Next try to generate by artisan new app key:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

After that restart your config file by:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Did that helped?

Comment: Its works fine in localhost. problem occur  after i upload it into cpanel shared host.

Comment: did u do all that i wrote on server?

Comment: i don't have shell access on the host

Comment: You need that. The best way is to connect by terminal by SSH protocol. Read about it. It is very useful.

Comment: and you are user that {{ csrf_field() }} is included in login panel on server? In html preview (in form section) you can see the token? Paste link if u can.

Comment: <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="6WamPaZGRA8rKzZijCB3ohLNu4mU9ZKbfM9wfxZF">

Comment: If it is code from server (not localhost) then you really need SSH and artisan  commands. Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't had SSH access on the host. So i tried run those command in my computer CMD then upload the project but i failed. Finally i create a another laravel project with the same version of my previous project. Then i copy and paste all the i have created such as controllers, views, request, model, helpers, web.php file and run command Auth and dumpautoload then upload the newly create project to the host. I also feel like its not the best way to do it. But its work for me.